# React Native AsyncStorage read the data after user input

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I have a question, so i'm using AsyncStorage to store the user input data as a json format. However , while i'm checking whether the data are stored correctly using console.log, it always print out undefined, so i'm curious about how to access the data i store and print it out so that i can check if the data is correct? thanks!

Here's the json formate that i want the user input to store in

```
  ////JSON FORMAT////
  const MyRecipeData = [
    {
      name: recipeName,
      video_cover: selectedVideoCover,
      video_url: UploadVideo,
      servings: servingSize,
      channel_name: channelName,
      publish_date: uploadDate,
      ingredients: ingredientsInput,
      directions: directionsInput,
    },
  ];
  ////JSON FORMAT////
```

and these are the function that called after the user pressing upload button, and i try to read it using getAllinput function, but not sure i did it right or not

```
  ////------- Save all DATA --------------------////
  const SaveAllInput = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("MyRecipeData", JSON.stringify(MyRecipeData))
      .then(() => {
        alert("your Recipe " + MyRecipeData.name + " has been saved");
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("error");
      });
    getAllInput();
  };
  ////------- Save all DATA --------------------////

  ////------- READING THE DATA THAT UPLOAD PREVIOUSLY-------- /////
  const getAllInput = async () => {
    try {
      const NewRecipeData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("MyRecipeData");
      NewRecipeData !== null ? JSON.parse(NewRecipeData) : null;
      console.log(NewRecipeData);
      return NewRecipeData;
    } catch {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  ////------- READING THE DATA THAT UPLOAD PREVIOUSLY-------- /////
```

the console.log(NewRecipeData) print out [{}] in my terminal, seems like i did not read my data properly

i tried to use getItem to read it out, but instead i got undefined or [{}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const NewRecipeData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("MyRecipeData");
NewRecipeData !== null ? JSON.parse(NewRecipeData) : null;
```

You using const and you are redefining the variable, try to console.log like this :

```
const NewRecipeData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("MyRecipeData");
console.log(NewRecipeData);
```

You are caliing   getAllInput(); without await

```
  const SaveAllInput = async () => {
    const MyRecipeData = [
      {
        name: recipeName,
        video_cover: selectedVideoCover,
        video_url: UploadVideo,
        servings: servingSize,
        channel_name: channelName,
        publish_date: uploadDate,
        ingredients: ingredientsInput,
        directions: directionsInput,
      },
    ];
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('MyRecipeData', JSON.stringify(MyRecipeData))
      .then(() => {
        alert('your Recipe ' + MyRecipeData.name + ' has been saved');
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('error');
      });
    await getAllInput();
  };
```

Comment: Sorry, i tried your method, but it still print out [{}] in the terminal

Comment: Can you share your code in https://snack.expo.dev/ so anyone can be reproduce the bug ?

Comment: @lawrencelu0904  You are caliing getAllInput(); without await

Comment: here's my code in snack.expo.dev https://snack.expo.dev/@lawrencelu/upload-user-input-async?platform=ios

Comment: i added the await before calling getAllInput(), but it still doesn't work

Comment: @lawrencelu0904    You need to paste MyRecipeData in SaveAllInput function

Comment: @lawrencelu0904 I updated answer above

Comment: omg it worked!! I'm really appreciate for your help @Quintis

Comment: but why do i have to wrote the json format inside the asyncStorage func ?

Comment: @lawrencelu0904 asyncStorage  save only string values , so if you want to save object you must stringify it. I f my answer helped you please mark it as answer )